# Android menu button not show

Tags: android, menu

I write an application.
It run on Android 2.3.4 phone, the menu can be pressed.
But if run on Android 4.0.3 TF201, the menu button not show.
How to let it show the menu button?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android 4.0 will discontinue the menu button. [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) is a nice article by android developers that says what to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give menu feature in android 4.0, you have to use **Action Bar** instead.Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use that menu use the following lines in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="9"
     android:targetSdkVersion="9" >
</uses-sdk>
```

Answer (score 0):

But sometimes you want a fullscreen app...for example in the Manifest is setted the activity with:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

The only and ugly fix is to set under the target sdk version:

http://lancelotmobile.com/blog/mobile-air-app-compatible-with-android-4/